# Can I tell if my TcpClient was established as a client or a server?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Given is an already connected TcpClient. Suppose the code which created the TcpClient is outside of my control.

I would like to know if it was created from a server (via `svr.AcceptTcpClient()`) or directly as a client (via `new TcpClient("host",123)`. Is it possible to tell?

I could store this information in a flag on creation, but I would not want to duplicate this information without actual need. I'm aware that the further usage is the exact same.

Comment: No, there is a misunderstanding. Running a TcpServer will yield each connection as a TcpClient, even though these TcpClients were created from a server. Compare with creating a TcpClient directly which connects to (said) TcpServer, thus a "real" client. This is what I was referring to.

Comment: Or maybe it is possible, have you tried checking the [`Active`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.active%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property?

Comment: The link seems to point to the "Active" property (?). It is protected, is there a way to subclass the result of the server's AcceptTcpClient? Then again, if I go that route, I might as well add a flag directly in the derived class. :)

Comment: Yeah, misread the property name, fixed. But I didn't notice it was protected. Then it seems like there really is no standard way.